# Achieve the output in one statement

Tags: c, algorithm

I was given this question by my school teacher. I was supposed to add in one statement in the C code and achieve this desired output.

I have tried but i am stuck. I think the main idea of this question is to establish the relationship between the int x[] and the y[] string as i increases from 0 to 6.

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, x[] = {-5,10,-10,-2,23,-20};

    char y[20] = "goodbye";

    char * p = y;

    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
        *(p + i) = //Fill in the one line statement here
    }

    y[6] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",p); //should print out "byebye"
}
```

Comment: It would print `byebye` or `bye bye`?

Comment: @output should be "byebye"

Comment: Suggestion: look at the ASCII table, figure out codes of characters that you are supposed to print. (This assignment is incredibly bad).

Comment: The simplest would be `*(p + i) += x[i];`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: I suppose you can't use `+=` `:)`.

Comment: Yep, same, six to one is a 1/2 dozen to another `:)`

Comment: @n.m. 'This assignment is incredibly bad' - seconded.  Now we can all vote on 'firing squad for teacher' :)

Comment: Hey!  Teacher!  Stop those bad homeworks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see the ascii value of the characters `b` is from 5 lesser than `g` and similarly for `y` it is 10 greater than `o`..so it will be (This meets the criteria of using `x`) (solution utilizing the values of `x`)

```
*(p+i) = (char)(*(p+i)+x[i]);
```

Yes one thing that is mentioned by `rici` is very important. `*(p+i)` is nothing other than `p[i]` - in fact it is much leaner to use and underneath it is still being calculated as `*(p+i)`.

From standard [6.5.2.1p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) C11 N1570

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets `[]` is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to the binary `+` operator, if `E1` is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the initial element of an array object) and `E2` is an integer, `E1[E2]` designates the `E2`-th element of `E1` (counting from zero).

The standard mentions this also. Being said this it would be as simple as

```
p[i]+=x[i];
```

---

Thoughts that came to my mind while solving.

- It would be (things that came to my mind when I saw it very first time - this is establishing no relation between `x` and `y`).

  ```
  *(p + i) = "byebye"[i];
  ```

  String literals are basically arrays and it decays into pointer to the first element of it and then we do this `*(decayed pointer + i)`.  This will eventually assign the characters of `"byebye"` to the `char` array `y`.
- Or something like this:- (too many hardcoded values - this does relate `x` and `y`)

  ```
  *(p+i) = *(y+4+i%3);
  ```

Comment: @Milk_QD.: Wait let me think - I find this interesting. You have to use `x` as well right?

Comment: The hint of the question given is to make use of the array variable x

Comment: @rici.: trust me I got it right now...before you said..haha

Comment: Rant: I really don't understand the value of asking students to write `*(p + i)` instead of `p[i]`. It's important to know that they mean the same thing, but giving the impression that the longer and more obscure vetsion is somehow better is counter-productive, imho. It is not better. `p[i]` is more readable.

Comment: God. am i expected to memorize ASCII table to be a programmer

Comment: @rici.: Now they give in assignment this kind of thing - kind of funny.  This is somewhat less relevant in learning C..but yes it's fun thing I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Using a the modulus operation you can manipulate your loop to assign `byebye` to the 6 `*char` values in `p`.

This works because you are starting from `y[4]` which is `'b'`.
The `6` in the `for` loop is your next hint. You need to iterate through `bye` twice.  `bye` has 3 characters.

This gives you:

```
*(p + i) = y[4+(i%3)];
```